# Selenium - click SVG dropdown to open expanded section of info

Tags: python, selenium, svg, web-scraping

Trying my first attempt at webscraping. I'm trying to pull some info that is accessed when you click about 20 different dropdown arrows from a list. I can't figure out how to click on all 20 arrows though. The HTML code looks like this for each dropdown section...

```
<button class="more" aria-label="Show more track info">
  <svg class="svg-icon icon-more">
    <use class="icon-use" xlink:href="https://mywebsiteblahblah.com#icon-down-angle">
      #shadow-root (closed)
        <svg id="icon-down-angle" viewBox="0 0 371 224">
          <path d="M184.857471,147.431517 L331.47257,0.816417666 L369.656336,39.0001839 L223.041237,185.615283 L223.117274,185.69132 L184.933508,223.875086 L184.857471,223.799049 L184.781434,223.875086 L146.597668,185.69132 L146.673705,185.615283 L0.0586051661,39.0001839 L38.2423714,0.816417666 L184.857471,147.431517 Z" transform="translate(.537 -.145)"></path>
        </svg>
    </use>
  </svg>
</button>
```

I can click the very first dropdown arrow by using...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,\"more\") and contains(@aria-label,\"Show more track info\")]"
).click()
```

but if I use `find_elements_by_xpath` I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_elements*` returns the list value.

You have to access it through an index like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")

#first element
elements[0].click()
```

Or:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath")[0].click()
```

Comment: That did the trick. I really appreciate the help. I've been stuck on this for a while!